# not the least of sth (is this a widely used expression or idiom? not the least of sth?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms

> This is true for several reasons , not the least of which is the fact that Massachusetts had the highest ratio of bodily injury claims to the number of accidents in the United States.

'not the least of sth' means 'most of sth'?

Comment: No. For a start, the expression is specifically "not the least of *which*". And there is no implication that it is the "most"; it's one reason among others, just not the smallest.

Comment: Thx. Literally true but wonder if it could mean also 'most' informally.

Comment: It doesn't mean 'most of which', but 'the one I'm about to mention (_reason_ in this case) is an important one (not the smallest)''.